# Best practice to create Service classes for Lightning Components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I'm coming from AngularJS background, and what I'm really missing in Lightning components is a Service layer. By 'Service' I mean here a singleton class, which could be injected to components, and could be used for sharing data and group reusable functions together.

I noticed that if I inject an external JS into a component, then it is initialized only once per application, even if it is injected to more than one component.

```
<ltng:require scripts="/resource/singleton_service" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptLoaded}"/>
```

--> here c.scriptLoaded is called only once per application.

So, theoretically it can be used to create a global singleton class and use it as a service. Are there any reasons to not to do this?

Are there any other recommended practices to share data between components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing to angular service in lightning is helper method. With Helper methods you can-

- Keep shared logic at application or component level via application
  helper method and component helper method respectively.
- Helper method is use to share code among same instance of component
  and components related through inheritance.
- Inherited methods can be overridden in sub components.

What you can't -

- Store data and share it across all the instance.
- A helper method shared across all the instances of different components in your application